# php multiple values in array

Tags: php, arrays

Need to add multiple values in following code .

```
$params = array('Source' => '531582253444', 
                'Destination' => $mob,
                'Mask' => $sender,
                'Message' => $message,
                'UniCode' => $unicode,   
                'Password' => '123');
```

above code working fine if $mob having single value like .

```
$mob = 531582253444
```

Need to add Like dynamically considering $mob as array

```
$params = array('Source' => '531582253444', 
                'Destination' => $mob,
                'Destination' => $mob,
                'Destination' => $mob,
                'Destination' => $mob,
                'Destination' => $mob,
                'Mask' => $sender,
                'Message' => $message,
                'UniCode' => $unicode,   
                'Password' => '123');
```

we have multiple values stored in array with variable name $mob .
we can add dynamically ?

Comment: There's no point in having the same key 'Destination' multiple times. The result array would contain the last 'Destination' key. Also, what exactly are you trying to achieve here? It's very unclear.

Comment: No, you cannot have multiple of the same key in an associative array.

You could, however, have unique keys each of whose corresponding values are arrays, and those arrays have multiple elements for each key.

Comment: @MalikIrfan Please revisit this abandoned question.  If one of the answers sufficiently handles your question, please award one of them the green tick of approval so that this question can be laid to rest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with [PHP Multidimensional Arrays](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp):

```
$params = array('Source' => '531582253444', 
                'Destination' => array($mob1, $mob2, $mob3),
                'Mask' => $sender,
                'Message' => $message,
                'UniCode' => $unicode,   
                'Password' => '123');
```

In this case you can add new item like this:

```
$params['Destination'][] = $mob4;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be fancy or if you have need in assoc array, you can do something similar to this:

```
foreach(array_leys($mob) as $key)
    $params['destination'][$key] = $mob[$key];
```